# BigQuery Array Manipulations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I need some help with BigQuery Array manipulation as follow:

Column1 represent the list of the content ids & Column2 represent the list of embedded content ids.

```
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    | Column1                                                                                | Column2                                                        |
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    |{"contentId":["1.5433912","1.5536755","1.5536970","1.5536380","1.5536809","1.5535567"]} |{'1.5433912':['1.5561001','1.5559520','1.5560946','1.5561026']} |
    |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------|
    |{"contentId":["1.5536141","1.5535574","1.5534770","1.5535870"]}                       |{'1.5535574':['1.5527726','1.5533354','1.5533093']}             |
    |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------|
    |{"contentId":["1.5561069","1.5557612","1.5561433"]}.                                    |{'1.5561069':['1.5527726'],'1.5561433':['1.5533093']}           |
    |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Desired output as follow:
[image]

Comment: explain the logic of output, so we can help you. meantime, i feel it is an error in your output example (just based on my reverse engineering option of your logic - but obviously this is just wild guess)

Comment: The output required merging both columns based on their "reference key" (i.e. 1.5433912 & 1.5535574). When merge happened the output list should also preserve the position of each content ids in array. For example on row#1 the reference key occurs at position 0 hence the output array should be all the content ids from that column2 followed by all the content ids from column1

Comment: so, references are in Column2 - right? can it hold few references? not just one as in your example

Comment: It's like sticking the array list from column2 to column1 based on the positional match.I hope I am able to explain it clearly.

Comment: so few references are possible - right?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Yes that's correct

Comment: can you update your question with example of at least two references in column2 so we are not making guesses

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I have added one more in question which contains the multiple references in Column2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(
  IF(REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(refs, ':')[OFFSET(1)], r"\[|\]|'", '')IS NULL, [TRIM(item, '"')],
    ARRAY(
      SELECT ref
      FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(refs, ':')[OFFSET(1)], r"\[|\]|'", ''))) AS ref WITH OFFSET
      ORDER BY OFFSET
    ))
  ORDER BY OFFSET) AS contentId
FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(Column1, '$.contentId')) AS item WITH OFFSET 
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Column2, r"'.*?':\[.*?\]")) refs
ON STARTS_WITH(refs, "'" || TRIM(item, '"'))
GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', t)
```

If to apply to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '{"contentId":["1.5433912","1.5536755","1.5536970","1.5536380","1.5536809","1.5535567"]}' Column1, "{'1.5433912':['1.5561001','1.5559520','1.5560946','1.5561026']}" Column2 UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"contentId":["1.5536141","1.5535574","1.5534770","1.5535870"]}', " {'1.5535574':['1.5527726','1.5533354','1.5533093']} " UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"contentId":["1.5561069","1.5557612","1.5561433"]}', "{'1.5561069':['1.5527726'],'1.5561433':['1.5533093']}"
)
SELECT ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(
  IF(REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(refs, ':')[OFFSET(1)], r"\[|\]|'", '')IS NULL, [TRIM(item, '"')],
    ARRAY(
      SELECT ref
      FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(refs, ':')[OFFSET(1)], r"\[|\]|'", ''))) AS ref WITH OFFSET
      ORDER BY OFFSET
    ))
  ORDER BY OFFSET) AS contentId
FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(Column1, '$.contentId')) AS item WITH OFFSET 
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Column2, r"'.*?':\[.*?\]")) refs
ON STARTS_WITH(refs, "'" || TRIM(item, '"'))
GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', t)
```

result is exactly as in your expected example

```
Row contentId    
1   1.5561001    
    1.5559520    
    1.5560946    
    1.5561026    
    1.5536755    
    1.5536970    
    1.5536380    
    1.5536809    
    1.5535567    
2   1.5536141    
    1.5527726    
    1.5533354    
    1.5533093    
    1.5534770    
    1.5535870    
3   1.5527726    
    1.5557612    
    1.5533093
```

Comment: Thank you @mikhail for your answer. Can you please let me know the usage of GROUP BY clause in the logic.

Comment: initially, all the elements are being unnested into separate rows. after they all assembled you need tohave a way to group them back together. in your example there was no any ID or other field that could be used for this. In such cases - you kind of create hash of whole row and than group by that hash - so `FORMAT('%t', t)` is kind of such a hash of `t` row of original table